# Случайная замена одинаковых элементов списка Python

Tags: python

Час добрый. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно заменить определенные одинаковые элементы в списке на разные элементы из другого списка. То есть имеется два списка

```
список 1 = ['пример', 'пример', '♥♥♥', 'пример', '♥♥']
список 2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'текст']
```

И после обработки списка 1 по ключевому слову 'пример', нужно получить новый список, в котором не будут повторятся переменные из списка 2. Выходные данные должны быть примерно такими

```
список 1 после обработки = ['1', '6', '♥♥♥', 'текст', '♥♥']
```

Пробовал код по типу того что оставлю ниже, но он заменяет все ключевые слова на одну и ту же переменную

```
 for word in text_model_split:
                s = word
                l = s

                with open('short.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_short:
                    for line in file_short:
                        line = line.split('\n')
                        short_list.append(line[0])

                        random_element = random.choice(short_list)

                l = [i.replace('пример', f'{random_element}') for i in l]
                l = (''.join(l))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##dVDLicMwEL1PFXMJtsAs5HsIuBLjg9mMyQRbdmT5sLdsutgCtoRACAvbgtRCGnEkxQRCiBgezDzNe09qv/S2kfNh4LptlEZVyE1TA1Tc6SmmmEXm3x7M2fyZkz1ECb7015/fe70nozzozYLe1M9nHuYeFh6WHlYe7NGczMV@26NbUtRWxSe5tWdhgF7yvicv2LnUtIk70nHwEALub/jotn1ZVhSPdwWUjcJdgowskWRfkyo0xRmjJzhBeibCFwjk0hFpimOYXKwB3QlsxrmLMBpkO5xgRfJhmAO0iqUelYbhBg)

```py
import random

list1 = ['пример', 'пример', '♥♥♥', 'пример', '♥♥']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'текст']
replace = 'пример'

unique2 = sorted(set(list2))
random.shuffle(unique2)
for j, i in enumerate([i for i, e in enumerate(list1) if e == replace]):
    list1[i] = unique2[j % len(unique2)]

print(list1)
```

Вывод:

```
['4', 'текст', '♥♥♥', '2', '♥♥']
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но такая же проблема, как и с ответом ниже. Можно ли брать случайные переменные из второго списка чтобы подставить их под замену?

Comment: @Дмитрий Поправил мой ответ (код), чтобы бралась случайная замена. Прочитайте ещё раз мой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, помогло)

Comment: @Atry подскажите пожалуйста как можно заменить только первый элемент из нескольких одинаковых?

Comment: @Дмитрий Если нужно заменить только первый, тогда просто нужно добавить `break` в последнюю строку тела цикла, [вот пример кода](https://tio.run/##dVBLasMwEN3PKWYTbIEJ5NMuAj6J8cJJxmRSW3ZkeZFdklvkAD1CoJRCriBdoRdxJcUUQqkYHkhv5r03ao9618jFMHDdNkqjKuS2qQEq7vQMU8wic7cn82G@zM2eogT/3L@v74/6n4zyoDcPejP/Pvew8LD08OLh1YO9mJv5tGd7cUOK2qrYkBt7FgboJR968oKdS03buCMdBw8h4LHDtNv1ZVlRPPYKKBuF@wQZWSLJviZVaIozRk9wgvRMhC8QyKUj0hTHMLlYAboT2IxzF2E0yPY4wYrkr2EeGteKijeAVrHUo@Yw/AA), по этой ссылке тот же код что в моём ответе, только `break` добавлен.

Comment: И снова благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

arr1 = ['пример', 'пример', '♥♥♥', 'пример', '♥♥']
arr2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'текст']
res = []

x = []
for el in arr1:
    if el not in x and arr1.count(el) > 1:
        x.append(el)

for i in range(len(arr1)):
    if arr1[i] not in x:
        res.append(arr1[i])
    else:
        n = random.randrange(len(arr2))
        res.append(arr2[n])
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, но он не заменяет элементы на случайные элементы из второго списка
Т.е. сколько не запускай, а в res результат всегда будет ['1', '2', '♥♥♥', '4', '♥♥']

Answer (score 1):

еще один похожий вариант, с использованием встроенной функции `iter()`:

```
from random import shuffle

list1 = ['пример', 'пример', '♥♥♥', 'пример', '♥♥']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'текст']
replace = 'пример'

shuffle(list2)
shuf = iter(set(list2))

list1 = [next(shuf) if i==replace else i for i in list1]
print(list1)  # ['текст', '3', '♥♥♥', '1', '♥♥']
```

**UPD**
только сейчас сообразил, что код выдаст ошибку после исчерпания итератора, то есть `list2` должен быть длиннее чем количество одинаковых элементов в `list1`